# Critique: logo for a health product

Tags: logo, critique

I’d like to know what you guys think about the logo below, there is some debate about the feathers of the tail, they are supposed to evoke an organic feeling, but others say they seem carelessly made.

Should the shape of the feathers be more like the shape of the body (simpler curves and appeareance) or stay the way they look now?

Apart from that what you guys think of the overall design? The product uses vibrations to heal certain ailments of the user.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: All I see when I look at those feathers are sperm.  Also, like someone else mentioned, the varying thickness of the neck really sticks out too.

Comment: @JohnManly Wow, now that you mention it, I can't unsee the sperm.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I'm not sure what that says about me, but that was the first thing I noticed haha.  It sticks out so much and distracts from everything else in the logo.

Answer (score 3):

My impression is that the variation in overall line vocabulary is unsettling.

There's precision in the circles. There's an attempt at precision in the neck (but it's not quite smooth), and there's no precision in the tail. This does, in fact, make the tail look "messy" and not "organic" to me.

I think you need to settle on a line style. Everything needs to either be precise or not. There are ways to imply organic but still be precise.

I also wonder how well they right side of the body circles will hold up when the logo is reduced.

I "get" peacock.. or even roadrunner... I don't "get" vibration or medical from the image at all. That's not to say this is a *problem*. Logos don't *have* to be literal by any means. And for all I know the company name could be "bird" related.

Comment: "overall line vocabulary is unsettling" = very eloquent phrase. I'm stealing that for future critiques.

Comment: @DA01 I agree. I have no idea why this board hasn't been renamed Scott.StackExchange.com yet.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I have is you mention organic which wont have a perfect shape to it but the body of the bird is deliberate and not in an organic fashion:

[image]

then look at the wings:

[image]

In regards to the wings...  I would suggest another shape other then what you have chosen because when you told me "medical" and its a symbol of medical I related to something I dont need to mention here.

I would consider another approach, as you mentioned, and make the wings flow with the body and neck better.  Also, I dont see how your logo gives the impression of medical healing or medical aliments.

I would ask yourself why you're choosing a bird and what about that bird will make you feel it is healing.  Maybe you can do a minimalist approach an use part of the bird's wings and the body be that in the mixture shape of a bird and an organic shape.