# Logo Critique: Logo for a freelance web developer

Tags: logo

I'm working on a logo for a web developer friend of mine who plans to start his freelance career.

Here are the specific questions I need help with:

Which layout works best, horizontal (mark on left) or vertical (mark on top)?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ricardo Zea. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at our [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I read the guidelines and edited my question. Is this Ok then? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's actually worse in my opinion. There's no *actual specific* question anywhere and you removed the images. "Any feedback" is **not** specific. Please reread the guidelines.

Comment: I didn't know editing removed the images… ¬¬. So, I guess I gotta be strictly literal here…

Comment: Ok, there you go, that Ok now? :)

Comment: It's a tad broad, but overall **much** better.

Comment:  sheesh. Ok, why still on hold then

Comment: Because a Moderator needs to reopen it.

Comment: Officially, @Scott, it's not a 'moderator' that needs to reopen it (although we can, as exceptions), but the question has entered the review queue to be reopened. High-rep users need to vote on whether to reopen the question or leave it closed.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. I see some improvement, but as-is, I'd immediately vote to re-close the question because now it is too broad: you are asking multiple questions at once. Please understand that Stack Exchange is aimed at objective questions that can be answered objectively, and critique questions are already a weird, subjective fit in a site that is a weird, subjective fit in the system itself.

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to post your images and your request for feedback in [The Looking Glass](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass), our critique chatroom. There's very little stringent rules over there, and you can ask away. Be sure to advert your post in [The Ink Spot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot), as the 'Glass is somewhat empty regularly.

Comment: Man, these StackExchange communities are so uptight, I knew SO was always like that but never expected this design community to be just like SO. Either way, thanks for the note. Can we just delete this question then, it hasn't helped anyone here and has brought me more headaches than I ever expected, not to mention it's not even accessible to the public. Thanks for the alternative links BTW.

Comment: I also want to say that I see other "critique" posts around here without ONE specific question AND asking for a general opinion about the design: _"Apart from that what you guys think of the overall design? "_ https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/critique-logo-for-a-health-product?rq=1 - Just plain weird how you go about considering what "works" and what "doesn't". 

Comment: The other question is also not that great. Yours is just more opinion-based and has quite broad. Check the answer that you got with your question - is that useful even to you? "I prefer A" - based on nothing? We're filtering questions that can be useful to the community, not just a single user, hence the close vote. Plus what Vincent said.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer A - it appears to stand out more to me.

Comment: Welcome SarahB. No worries, since the question was also a beginners question and also did not provide much explanation and context, your answer did not break any rules. Please stay around and enjoy this exchange site.

Comment: Hi SarahB, welcome. If you want to know more about the site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to get you up to speed. Main message is that we are a Q&A site with some stricter rules about what goes where, and not a forum. Please stick around and enjoy!